# Сортировка фото по похожести ( по лицам) как осуществить?

Tags: java, android, сортировка, нейронные-сети, распознавание-образов

Есть множество библиотек на Java, использующие нейросети: `tensorflow, оболочка под opencv, Google Cloud Vision API`. Например, распознать лица - не проблема. У меня в папке лежат несколько фото и мне их необходимо отсортировать по похожести ( например, по лицам). Как мне их отсортировать? Какую библиотеку можно использовать? Можно на словах объяснить.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего то что вы ищете называется face identification - как правило это коммерческие технологии для идентификации по лицу, которые используют всякие правительственные и не только организации. Начните со списка https://facedetection.com/software/